# angular 4 child component not destroying in detail view

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a master/detail view setup with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

In my details view component I have another child component that has one way bindings based off data I get from the new detail view data.

This is my master view

```
<div *ngFor="let rs of resources">
    {{rs.name}}
    <a [routerLink]="['id', rs.id]">details</a>

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my detail view

```
<div>
    {{resource.id}}
    <sub-detail [resource]="resource"></sub-details>
</div>
```

It works once on load but when I navigate to another detail view, that child component stays. It does not get destroyed and there's no new data and the data from the last detail view state exists.

How do I update child components in a detail view on a router outlet?

```
{
        path: 'master',
        component: MasterComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:':id',
                component:DetailView,
            }
        ]
},
```

Comment: can you add more detail? show us the template for the detail/child component. What is your route?

Comment: updated information

Comment: I think I found the problem... [()] instead of []?

Comment: are you sure you want to create a <router-outlet> inside a *ngFor loop?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code to reflect changes

Answer (score 0):

creating a  inside a *ngFor loop will break the router in a way you are describing